# Can't boot linux server with LILO

Tags: linux, debian, boot

I've got an old linux server that failed to boot this morning.  It's running Debian stable.  I get the following on the console:

`LILO 22.8 Loading Linux......................................................................................................................................................... ............`

And it just sits there.  Any idea what is going on or how I can fix this?

Update: I've tried loading the LinuxOLD config and I get a little further but I then get the following error:

`VFS: Cannot open root device "302" or unknown-block(3,2)
Please append a correct "root=" boot option
Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(3,2)`

Update2: I was able to boot my system using [RIP Linux](http://www.tux.org/pub/people/kent-robotti/looplinux/rip/).  In it's boot menu I chose to boot a specific partition (I chose /dev/hda2 where I have my root fs installed) and it booted no problem.  However, if I boot try to boot using LILO that's installed on my hard drive I still have the same issue (even explicitly specifying /dev/hda2 as the root fs like I did with RIP).  I looked in my lilo.conf and everything seemed valid.  Any ideas what is wrong with my LILO setup?  I don't know quite enough about the linux boot process to really diagnose things.  I assume I'm using RIP linux's initrd when booting from the CD, so maybe my initrd is somehow messed up?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like it might be a hard disk issue.  Use a boot disk ([UBCD?](http://www.ultimatebootcd.com/)) to run disk diagnostics.  You could also use a Linux rescue disk to attempt to access the filesystem and verify the configuration.

System was working before, right?  If so, have any changes been made to the system recently?

Answer (score 1):

Your kernel apparently can't find either its initrd, or the root filesystem. If you didn't update your kernel, then most probably your disk or filesystem is hosed. Boot using a live CD to check your root filesystem state.

Answer (score 0):

Try running LILO with the -v option to get verbose output.  This may provide more insight into your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  How do I pass that flag to LILO?  My only option is to get the LILO boot menu by pressing shift when LILO is starting...

Comment: in lilo.conf.  verbose=5 gives maximum output.